# arduino code problem with 3des encypt decrypt

Tags: encryption, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, 3des

Hello i have problem with my code in 3des enc/dec it work only with 8 byte for me

i got result only this

the problem is result give only for 8 byte first not for all 48 byte

B1 09 DA E1 B7 1B 63 8E 17 02 07 83 1A 0D 1A DF 36 1F E4 6D 41 28 35 25 02 00 00 14 00 00 43 77 3B 38 98 37 15 20 F7 0C 18 56 03 00 00 14 00 00

below i attach my example code

```
#include <DES.h>

DES des;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");
}

void loop() {
  tdesTest();
  delay(2000);
}

void tdesTest()
{
  byte out[48];
  byte in[48] = { 0xda, 0x9f, 0xab, 0xbe, 0x85, 0x26, 0x6f, 0x53, 0x9c, 0x8c, 0xbb, 0x03, 0x7f, 0x54, 0x61, 0x27, 0x3d, 0xfa, 0xb9, 0xf5, 0xfe, 0xb0, 0x9a, 0x3b, 0x3b, 0xc6, 0xf8, 0xb5, 0xe0, 0x84, 0x4d, 0xe1, 0x58, 0xe7, 0x88, 0x83, 0xae, 0x0d, 0xae, 0xdf, 0x36, 0x0d, 0xd0, 0x68, 0x45, 0x2b, 0x37, 0x24 };

  byte key[] = { 
                  0x15, 0x2b, 0xd8, 0x96, 0x57, 0xe0, 0x3f, 0xdc, 
                  0x73, 0x75, 0xa0, 0x0e, 0x1f, 0xb1, 0xa3, 0x8b, 
                  0xab, 0x09, 0x7c, 0x10, 0x3b, 0x80, 0x38, 0x46,
                };

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");

  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);

  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
}

void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
  {

   if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }

    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any question, any indication on what you're trying to achieve or what output you expect.

Comment: my problem is in encyption or decyption i got only 8 byte in result

Comment: Ah you need to use a **mode of operation** to turn a block cipher in a (CPA secure) generic cipher. See Wikipedia for a couple of modes. DES? The seventies are over ... MAN!

Comment: mode of operation is 3des i attch my code example is work just my problem is in 8 byte only

Comment: 3DES is not a mode of operation. It performs an encrypt, decrypt and then encrypt again *on a single 8 byte block*. It turns DES in a stronger cipher requiring a larger key, but it doesn't change the usage of it.

Comment: i don't know this i use this lib
https://github.com/spaniakos/ArduinoDES

Comment: Oh, for goodness sake: https://github.com/spaniakos/ArduinoDES/blob/master/examples/DesedeCBC-easy/DesedeCBCexample.ino . Note that that example doesn't correctly pads the plaintext (if I'm looking at the right piece of code).